# Passing options to lintian in pdebuild

Tags: debian, packaging, pbuilder, lintian

debuild has an option `--lintian-opts` that allows to pass options to lintian. How can I pass options to lintian from pdebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`debuild` calls `lintian` directly, which is why it has an option to pass arguments to it. `pdebuild` doesn’t.

If you want to add a `lintian` invocation to your `pdebuild` run, you’d typically add a `pbuilder` hook, and specify options there. See `/usr/share/doc/pbuilder/examples/B90lintian` for an example hook, and [How do I run lintian from pbuilder-dist?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140697/412264) for details of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. That showed me how to invode lintian. I added some code to pass options to it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extended version of `B90lintian` that supports passing options to lintian:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

BUILDDIR="${BUILDDIR:-/tmp/buildd}"

if [ "$LINT" = 1 ] || [ -n "$LINTOPTS" ]; then
    apt-get install -y "${APTGETOPT[@]}" lintian
    
    # Because pbuilder has not home directory, calling su - pbuilder will print
    # su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
    # To avoid that warning and to provide the proper current working directory for any
    # relative file names used in LINTOPTS, set pbuilder's home directory to source
    # directory, which is the (only) subdirectory of the build directory
    usermod --home "$BUILDDIR"/*/ pbuilder

    echo "I: start of lintian output"
    # use this version if you want lintian to fail the build
    #su -c "lintian -I --show-overrides $LINTARGS $BUILDDIR/*.changes" - pbuilder
    # use this version if you don't want lintian to fail the build
    su -c "lintian -I --show-overrides $LINTOPTS $BUILDDIR/*.changes; :" - pbuilder
    echo "I: end of lintian output"
fi
```

The environment variables `LINT` and `LINTOPTS` can be used to invoke lintian and pass some options to it.